# When is the cookie set by AJAX available in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I'm doing an AJAX call and setting a cookie in the user browser in the response (the server code sets the cookie). I noticed in the success callback from the ajax, the cookie is not available. When I look in `document.cookie` the new cookie is not there.

My question, when can I be certain that the new cookie is there? if not in the success callback, maybe on a timeout with 100ms? 1s? indeterminate?

Comment: I think it's ought to be a rule in stackoverflow that when you downvote/vote to close you must write a comment or a private message that explains why...

Answer (score 7):

Just to be clear here, when you say "in the success callback" -- is the Set-Cookie HTTP Response header in the response returned to the XmlHttpRequest? If so, the cookie should be visible at that time.

Have you checked in the browser's Developer Tools network tab?

If it's not visible at that time, it might be because the cookie had the `httponly` attribute set and thus it will never be visible to JavaScript.

Comment: FYI - XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() "Returns all headers from the response, with the exception of those whose field name is Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2." http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders%28%29-method,